# Ternary model association in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, uml

I've modeled a UML class Diagram like this

[image: UML Diagram with ternary association]

I want to translate this association to Django. I have the following:

```
class Crypto(models.Model):
    cryptoName = models.CharField(max_length=64, primary_key=True)

class Worker(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=128, primary_key=True)
    tlf = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    cryptos = models.ManyToManyField(Crypto)

class Operation(models.Model):
    refNum = models.IntegerField()
    datetime = models.DateTimeField()
    amount = models.FloatField()
    amountCrypto = models.FloatField()
```

I'm stuck at trying to represent the ternary association. Django has the `through` attr for `ManyToManyField` but, as you can see, the association is not m2m in any way, but mostly one-to-many. So how is the best way to represent this ternary association with Django models?

---

Edit: There will be cryptocurrencies registered in the database and what workers can do is enable using as many as they want (or disable, if it’s the case).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want a worker has many cryptocurrencies. Then there are two use cases that will define what you must be using `ManyToManyField` or `ForeignKey`.

## If cryptocurrency objects for all users are always different from one another.

> For example, If the user is registering themselves and can create
>   there own cryptocurrencies which are always different than already available
>   currencies.

You must add a **ForeignKey** in your `Crypto` model instead of using **ManyToManyField** inside `Worker` model.

```
class Crypto(models.Model):
    cryptoName = models.CharField(max_length=64, primary_key=True)
    worker = models.ForeignKey(Worker, related_name='cryptos')

    def __str__(self):
       return self.cryptoName
```

*Remove cryptos **ManyToManyField** relation from Worker model*

In that way, you can have many cryptos related to a worker and you can access cryptos of a worker using the `related_name` mentioned in the field

```
worker = Worker.objects.first()
worker.cryptos
# output: <QuerySet [<Crypto: IOT>, <Crypto: BTC>, ...]>
```

---

## If the user can choose from already available cryptocurrencies while Registering

> That means multiple users are linking with the same object of crypto
>   and a user can choose as many currencies.

You must use **`ManyToManyField`** as you are using now.

And you can simply access those currencies objects of a worker using

```
worker.cryptos
# output: <QuerySet [<Crypto: IOT>, <Crypto: BTC>, ...]>
```

For linking a cryptocurrency to a worker you can use [**`.add()`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/)

```
crypto = Crypto.objects.get(cryptoName='BTC')
worker.cryptos.add(crypto)
```

**UPDATE**

When you create **ManyToManyField** Relation, then behind the scene a table is created which keep the references of both models, But if you want to create your own middle table you have to use `through` keyword while defining **ManyToManyField**

```
class Worker(models.Model):
    ...
    # rest of the fields 
    cryptos = models.ManyToManyField(Crypto, through='Operation', related_name='workers')
```

and add the foreign key of both models manually to `Operation` model.

```
class Operation(models.Model):
    ...
    # rest of fields
    worker = models.ForeignKey(Worker, related_name='operation')
    crypto = models.ForeignKey(Crypto, related_name='operation')
```

> Check out the [`official docs`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships) for more info on how to use it.

Comment: Thank you! I think it’s sufficient with the foreign key since in this case I want all different workers to have as many currencies as they register. However, I thought that many to many relationships (as this is the case if I’m not wrong) where represented by this **ManyToManyField** in Django and Foreign keys where used in case of one-to-many relationships. Are you suggesting that I should modify the class diagram so **handles** association between Worker and Cryptocurrency becomes one-to-many?

Comment: @oneberenjena No, There are two use cases, check my updated answer.

Comment: Now I got it. That’s exactly my need, since cryptocurrencies will be available for users to enabling/disabling them in their apps but they can’t register any crypto they want creating different objects. Thank you. However I’m still stuck at representing the ternary association between **Worker**, **Crypto** and **Operation**.

Comment: Check the update section in my answer, you must need `through` keywords

Comment: @oneberenjena  does it helped?